How to train a continuous-time normalizing flow model?
I'm confused on how we can actually train a continuous-time normalizing flow model. There are two use cases for the discrete-time (original) normalizing flows, and I've tried to outline how I would do both cases with a continuous time flow. Can you help me with this? Questions for each part are in bold.
I'll let $f_\phi(t, z_t)$ be my neural network, so we have that $z_t = z_0 + \int_0^t f(\tau, z) d\tau$, and we have that $\log p_t(z_t) = \log p_0(z_0) - \int_0^t Tr(D_z f)$.
I am assuming I have some ODE solver that can track gradients of $f_\phi$ when I use it. It should take in arguments $z_0, dz/dt, \log p_0(z_0), t_0 = 0, t_1 = 1$ and output $z_1, \log p_1(z_1)$ (and track the gradients $D_\phi f_\phi$). Note that can estimate $z_t$ with initial condition $z_0$ and derivative $f$ without computing the transport of $\log p_0$ to $\log p_t$.
I'll use $u = z_0$ to denote variables on the $t = 0$ (base) side of the NF and $x = z_1$ for the output side, $t = 1$.
My base density will always be $p_u = p_0 = N(0,I)$.

The first use case is when we have a data set $\{x_i\}$ and we assume the are IID samples from an unknown density $p_x^*$. In this case, to train the NF, I think we want to maximize the likelihood of the data. The only way I can figure out how to do this is to use the ODE solver (and track gradients) backwards, so we let $z_1 = x_i$ and call
ode_solver(x_i, f, ???,  t_0 = 1, t_1 = 0). My first problem is I don't know what to put for the $p_x(x)$ into the ode solver. What goes here? Note that in the code here, line 139 shows they pass in $\log p_x=0$ which makes no sense to me.

Supposing we ignore that and use the ODE solver only on the data. It will provide $z_0 = u_i$. Then I can write $\sum \log p_0(u_i)$ (b/c $p_0 = N(0,I)$, and since the $u_i$ depend on $\phi$  we can maximize this in $\phi$. But I don't think this won't be a good loss function b/c it ignores the transport of the probability densities.
Can someone help me understand how to train this? Note in the code base linked above, they subtract the transported probabilities $\log p_u$ (that started as all 0s before the ode solver) from the loss I mentioned (line 186). Why?

The second use case is when we can compute (the log of) some intractable   density $p^*_x$ up to a constant  (we can compute $\log(p_x^*(x)) + C$ for any $x$, and we wish to sample from it. So my plan is to minimize $KL(p_x, p_x^*)$. To execute this I'll sample $u_i~p_u = N(0,I)$ and compute $w_i = \log p_u(u_i)$. I'll pass these to the forward pass of the ODE solver,

ode_solver(u_i, f, w_i, t_0 =0, t_1 = 1) and get out the $x_i = z_1$ and the $\log p_x(x_i)$. Then I can write the monte-carlo simulation of $KL(p_x, p_x^*)$ as my loss:
$$L(\phi) = -\tfrac{1}{n}\sum_i \log p_x(x_i) - \log p_x^*(x_i)$$ (both log terms depend on $\phi$).
Does this seem right for the second use case?
Thanks for any help!
